# How to theme uitableview uiview and friends

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I have a bunch of uiviews and uitable views.  How can I theme them the same way you might make a stylesheet for html pages?

What is the best way to use a custom shared appearance properties across my iphone application

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont think is possible using something like stylesheet!

I would advice you to theme your views as much as possible in the interface builder! but in this approach you will have to do it again, again and again!

Or you can have your custom components, such as, CustomTableView, which has all your themes! the issue about it, is that you cannot visualize your custom component in Interface Builder.

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at the [Three20](http://three20.info/) library - it sounds like it's got exactly what you're looking for. I found a helpful looking tutorial [here](http://mattvague.com/three20-stylesheets-tutorial).